# When to close the channel?

Tags: netty

In netty 3.5.x demos, the channel is closed after channel.write(response) is called, either by explicit closing or by adding a "ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE".
My question is , should we close every channel everytime we done writing someting? Even though we are using keepalive connections?

Answer (score 2):

Only close the channel if you want to "disconnect".

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response!I just went over the netty source code. I noticed the channel is actually a wrapper of nio socketchannel which get closed by eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk). But I found this only get called in sendDownstream method. What is the design purpose of not closing the socket in a sendUpstream method? thanks